# exactly once delivery Is it possible through spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka or spring-kafka which one to use

Tags: spring-kafka, manual

I am trying to achieve exactly once delivery using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka in a spring boot application.
The versions I am using are:

- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core-1.2.1.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.2.1.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-stream-codec-1.2.2.RELEASE spring-kafka-1.1.6.RELEASE
- spring-integration-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE
- spring-integration-core-4.3.10.RELEASE
- zookeeper-3.4.8
- Kafka version : 0.10.1.1

This is my configuration (cloud-config):

```
    spring:
      autoconfigure:
        exclude: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.servo.ServoMetricsAutoConfiguration
      kafka:
        consumer:
          enable-auto-commit: false
      cloud:
        stream:
          kafka:
            binder:
              brokers: "${BROKER_HOST:xyz-aws.local:9092}"
              headers:
                - X-B3-TraceId
                - X-B3-SpanId
                - X-B3-Sampled
                - X-B3-ParentSpanId
                - X-Span-Name
                - X-Process-Id
              zkNodes: "${ZOOKEEPER_HOST:120.211.316.261:2181,120.211.317.252:2181}"
            bindings:
              feed_platform_events_input:
                consumer:
                  autoCommitOffset: false
          binders:
            xyzkafka:
              type: kafka
          bindings:
            feed_platform_events_input:
              binder: xyzkafka
              destination: platform-events
              group: br-platform-events
```

I have two main classes:
**FeedSink Interface:**

```
package au.com.xyz.proxy.interfaces;
import org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input; 
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

public interface FeedSink {

String FEED_PLATFORM_EVENTS_INPUT = "feed_platform_events_input";

@Input(FeedSink.FEED_PLATFORM_EVENTS_INPUT)
MessageChannel feedlatformEventsInput();
}
```

**EventConsumer**

```
package au.com.xyz.proxy.consumer;

@Slf4j
@EnableBinding(FeedSink.class)
public class EventConsumer {

    public static final String SUCCESS_MESSAGE =
            "SEND-SUCCESS : Successfully sent message to platform.";
    public static final String FAULT_MESSAGE = "SOAP-FAULT Code: {}, Description: {}";
    public static final String CONNECT_ERROR_MESSAGE = "CONNECT-ERROR Error Details: {}";
    public static final String EMPTY_NOTIFICATION_ERROR_MESSAGE =
            "EMPTY-NOTIFICATION-ERROR Empty Event Received from platform";

    @Autowired
    private CapPointService service;

    @StreamListener(FeedSink.FEED_PLATFORM_EVENTS_INPUT)
    /**
     * method associated with stream to process message.
     */
    public void message(final @Payload EventNotification eventNotification,
                        final @Header(KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT) Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {

        String caseMilestone = "UNKNOWN";
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(eventNotification)) {
            SysMessage sysMessage = processPayload(eventNotification);
            caseMilestone = sysMessage.getCaseMilestone();
            try {
                ClientResponse response = service.sendPayload(sysMessage);
                if (response.hasFault()) {
                    Fault faultDetails = response.getFaultDetails();
                    log.error(FAULT_MESSAGE, faultDetails.getCode(), faultDetails.getDescription());
                } else {
                    log.info(SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
                }
                acknowledgment.acknowledge();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(CONNECT_ERROR_MESSAGE, e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            log.error(EMPTY_NOTIFICATION_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        }
    }



    private SysMessage processPayload(final EventNotification eventNotification) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String jsonString =  gson.toJson(eventNotification.getData());
        log.info("Consumed message for platform events with payload : {} ", jsonString);
        SysMessage sysMessage = gson.fromJson(jsonString, SysMessage.class);
        return sysMessage;
    }
    }
```

I have set the autocommit property for Kafka and spring container as false.
if you see in the EventConsumer class I have used Acknowledge in cases where I service.sendPayload is successful and there are no Exceptions. And I want container to move the offset and poll for next records.
What I have observed is:

- Scenario 1 - In case where the Exception is thrown and there are no new messages published on kafka. There is no retry to process the message and it seems there is no activity. Even if the underlying issue is resolved. The issue I am referring to is down stream server unavailability. Is there a way to retry the processing n times and then give up. Note this is retry of processing or repoll from the last committed offset. This is not about Kafka instance not available.
  If I restart the service (EC2 instance) then the processing happens from the offset where the last successful Acknowledge was done.
- Scenario 2 - In case where Exception happened and then a subsequent message is pushed to kafka. I see the new message is processed and the offset moved. It means I lost the message which was not acknowledged. So the question is if I have handled the Acknowledge. How do I control to read from last commit not just the latest message and process it. I am assuming there is internally a poll happening and it did not take into account or did not know about the last message not being acknowledged. I don't think there are multiple threads reading from kafka. I dont know how the @Input and @StreamListener annotations are controlled. I assume the thread is controlled by property consumer.concurrency which controls the thread and by default it is set to 1.

So I have done research and found a lot of links but unfortunately none of them answers my specific questions.
I looked at (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/575)
which has a comment from Marius (https://stackoverflow.com/users/809122/marius-bogoevici):

> Do note that Kafka does not provide individual message acking, which
>   means that acknowledgment translates into updating the latest consumed
>   offset to the offset of the acked message (per topic/partition). That
>   means that if you're acking messages from the same topic partition out
>   of order, a message can 'ack' all the messages before it.

not sure if it is the issue with order when there is one thread.

Apologies for long post, but I wanted to provide enough information. The main thing is I am trying to avoid losing messages when consuming from kafka and I am trying to see if spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka can do the job or I have to look at alternatives.

**Update 6th July 2018**

I saw this post https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/431
Is this a better approach to my problem? I can try latest version of spring-kafka

```
@KafkaListener(id = "qux", topics = "annotated4", containerFactory = "kafkaManualAckListenerContainerFactory",
                containerGroup = "quxGroup")
public void listen4(@Payload String foo, Acknowledgment ack, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
```

- Will this help in controlling the offset to be set to where the last
  successfully processed record? How can I do that from the listen
  method. consumer.seekToEnd(); and then how will listen method reset to get the that record?
- Does putting the Consumer in the signature provide support to get
  handle to consumer? Or I need to do anything more?
- Should I use Acknowledge or consumer.commitSyncy()
- What is the significance of containerFactory. do I have to define it
  as a bean.
- Do I need @EnableKafka and @Configuration for above approach to work?
  Bearing in mind the application is a Spring Boot application.
- By Adding Consumer to listen method I don't need to implement
  ConsumerAware Interface?

Last but not least, Is it possible to provide some example of above approach if it is feasible.

**Update 12 July 2018**

Thanks Gary (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1240763/gary-russell) for providing the tip of using maxAttempts. I have used that approach. And I am able to achieve exactly once delivery and preserve the order of the message.

My updated cloud-config:

```
    spring:
      autoconfigure:
        exclude: org.springframework.cloud.netflix.metrics.servo.ServoMetricsAutoConfiguration
      kafka:
        consumer:
          enable-auto-commit: false
      cloud:
        stream:
          kafka:
            binder:
              brokers: "${BROKER_HOST:xyz-aws.local:9092}"
              headers:
                - X-B3-TraceId
                - X-B3-SpanId
                - X-B3-Sampled
                - X-B3-ParentSpanId
                - X-Span-Name
                - X-Process-Id
              zkNodes: "${ZOOKEEPER_HOST:120.211.316.261:2181,120.211.317.252:2181}"
            bindings:
              feed_platform_events_input:
                consumer:
                  autoCommitOffset: false
          binders:
            xyzkafka:
              type: kafka
          bindings:
            feed_platform_events_input:
              binder: xyzkafka
              destination: platform-events
              group: br-platform-events
              consumer:
                maxAttempts: 2147483647
                backOffInitialInterval: 1000
                backOffMaxInterval: 300000
                backOffMultiplier: 2.0
```

Event Consumer remains the same as my initial implementation. Except for rethrowing the error for the container to know the processing has failed. If you just catch it then there is no way container knows the message processing has failures. By doing acknoweldgement.acknowledge you are just controlling the offset commit. In order for retry to happen you must throw the exception. Don't forget to set the kafka client autocommit property and spring (container level) autocommitOffset property to false. Thats it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Marius, Kafka only maintains an offset in the log. If you process the next message, and update the offset; the failed message is lost.

You can send the failed message to a dead-letter topic (set `enableDlq` to true).

Recent versions of Spring Kafka (2.1.x) have special error handlers `ContainerStoppingErrorHandler` which stops the container when an exception occurs and `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` which will cause the failed message to be redelivered.

Comment: Can you please look at my update and provide your feedback. Much appreciated.

Comment: The framework takes care of all the wiring; the listener adapter can supply the consumer and/or ack as arguments if the method requires them. If you don't want to lose messages there are 3 or 4 options. 1) stop the container until the problem is resolved; 2) send the failed message to a dead-letter topic; 3) seek to current and re-deliver indefinitely 4) a combination of 2 and 3 - send to DLQ after some number of redeliveries. Recent spring-kafka releases support all of these; spring-cloud-stream currently only supports 2) and 4) (although 4) is implemented differently).

Comment: Another constraint I have is order, we have to maintain order. So DLQ will probably not work. Submit will have to go before update. I am interested to know the implementation detail for 3)  "seek to current and re-deliver indefinitely". Is this done in listen method? how can this be achieved. can seekToEnd be used or I have to store the offset somewhere? and how do I identify the correct partition for that listener?

Comment: With SCSt; a version of option 3) is available by setting the `maxAttempts` to a high value it doesn't seek but the retries are in-memory; option 1) is possible in 2.x by using the actuator to stop the binding.

Comment: Thanks Gary. Using maxAttempts worked for me. I have updated my post with what was updated in my code/config.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you suspend the consumer thread too long, the broker will think the consumer is dead and perform a rebalance. You need to increase the `max.poll.interval.ms` if you suspend the consumer for more than 5 minutes.

Comment: Hi Gary thanks for pointing this out. But as I understand I have to increase max.poll.interval.ms ( by default it is 5 secs), if backOffMaxInterval is set to higher value than 5 seconds. should I set it to a value just a shade below 5 seconds?

Comment: No; it's 5 minutes. If you have `maxAttempts: 2147483647`, and `backOffMaxInterval: 300000` you are effectively preventing polling the consumer for a very long time time (effectively infinity). You can't do that without increasing the max poll interval.

Comment: yeah sorry I meant 5 mins. Agree on it being a long time to poll. I am thinking if I can incorporate poll call in between the attempts somehow. Is there a way to get a handle to Consumer from method Annotated with @StreamListener?. I am trying to make sure If in future I scale and add another instance of service, and a rebalance happens then it should not impact the solution. Do you know what is the behaviour if there is one instance/consumer and that becomes unresponsive. Do we need to restart the service in that case?

Comment: In 2.0 and later you can get a reference to the `Consumer` via a `@Header` parameter (`KafkaHeaders.CONSUMER`). If there is only one consumer and the `max.poll.interval.ms` is exceeded, when the listener finally returns the offset commit will fail and the broker will re-balance - giving the single consumer its partitions again, and the record will be redelivered. If there are more than one consumer the partitions will be given to the other consumer; when this listener finally returns, another rebalance will occur. In either case you don't need to restart manually.